# Extracting classes from numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, mask

I am having a numpy array of data

```
data = np.random.random((5, 5))
```

and another numpy array of equal shape masking the first one with classes from `0` to `n`:

```
>>> mask
array([[3, 3, 1, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 1, 2, 2],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 3],
       [2, 1, 1, 0, 2],
       [0, 2, 3, 0, 2]])
```

What's the best way to compute a two-dimensional array with `n` rows, where each row contains all elements from `data` with class `row_idx` (described by `mask`)?

Comment: Please show example of result array

Comment: how about `data[ mask == 1 ]` to get all values which have `1` in mask.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it better than `O(n^2)` as you should iterate through all `mask` array. As the number of elements in each class can be different the result can't be numpy array (rows have different sizes). So I don't think you can avoid python loop here with pure numpy functions. I suggest this `O(n^2)` solution:

```
ans = [[] for i in range(mask.max() + 1)]
for k, v in np.ndenumerate(mask):
    ans[v].append(data[k])
```